# Parsing json data

Tags: python, json

I have a project which involves making RESTful web API calls and I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand what options there are in Python for parsing the data that I am getting back.

I'm not sure what this data type is called.

To get the data portion of the response, I did:

```
data = response.json()
```

Are there ways in Python I could use to parse this data? Essentially I want to be able to build a list from this. Say, look for multiple entries with the "name' key and build a list of all their values. What are the best ways to do this?

The data coming back looks like this:

```
[{'links': [{'href': '/v2/datacenters/ucos/au1', 'rel': 'self'}, {'href': '/v2/datacenters/ucos/au1/deploymentCapabilities', 'rel': 'deploymentCapabilities'}, {'href': '/v2/sharedLoadBalancers/ucos/au1', 'rel': 'loadBalancers', 'verbs': ['GET', 'POST']}, {'href': 'https://api.loadbalancer.ctl.io/ucos/au1/loadbalancers', 'rel': 'LBAAS', 'verbs': ['GET']}, {'href': '/v2/datacenters/ucos/au1/computeLimits', 'rel': 'computeLimits', 'verbs': ['GET', 'POST']}, {'href': '/v2/datacenters/ucos/au1/networkLimits', 'rel': 'networkLimits', 'verbs': ['GET']}, {'href': '/v2/vmImport/ucos/au1/available', 'rel': 'availableOvfs', 'verbs': ['GET']}, {'href': '/v2/datacenters/ucos/au1/bareMetalCapabilities', 'rel': 'bareMetalCapabilities'}], 'name': 'AU1 - APAC (Sydney)', 'id': 'au1'}, {'links': [{'href': '/v2/datacenters/ucos/ca1', 'rel': 'self'}, {'href': '/v2/datacenters/ucos/ca1/deploymentCapabilities', 'rel': 'deploymentCapabilities'}, {'href': '/v2/sharedLoadBalancers/ucos/ca1', 'rel': 'loadBalancers', 'verbs': ['GET', 'POST']}, {'href': 'https://api.loadbalancer.ctl.io/ucos/ca1/loadbalancers', 'rel': 'LBAAS', 'verbs': ['GET']}, {'href': '/v2/datacenters/ucos/ca1/computeLimits', 'rel': 'computeLimits', 'verbs': ['GET', 'POST']}, {'href': '/v2/datacenters/ucos/ca1/networkLimits', 'rel': 'networkLimits', 'verbs': ['GET']}, {'href': '/v2/vmImport/ucos/ca1/available', 'rel': 'availableOvfs', 'verbs': ['GET']}, {'href': '/v2/datacenters/ucos/ca1/bareMetalCapabilities', 'rel': 'bareMetalCapabilities'}], 'name': 'CA1 - Canada (Vancouver)', 'id': 'ca1'}
```

Comment: You can use the module `json`, specific method `json.loads()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Your output looks like it has already been converted into a lists and dicts, so you may not even need the json module.

Comment: take time to learn the language first, then to learn web application.

Comment: @Evert I think the same, although this method `data = response.json()` is confuse, but i dont understans why he say 'parse this data'....

Answer (score 0):

You have already parsed your data with `data = response.json()`

What you are showing below that is the string representation of this object, which is a list containing two dictionaries.

To access the data you can do something like this:

```
for d in data:
    print(d['name'])
    for l in d['links']:
        print("  " + l['href'])
    print("\n")
```

Comment: I guess I misquoted. I meant to say, how do I filter out the parts I need. I apologize, I am not familiar with the terms list and dictionary in python. In fact, I did not know what to even call this data type to do a search to see how to filter what I want.  I will definitely investigate that further. Thank you Mark_M, your solution works for helping me filter out what I want. I deeply appreciate you taking the time to look through the data i posted to help me understand how to read and reference it!